# Duplicating/Cloning Vector.<MovieClip>

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, duplicates

How do you duplicate the content of the Vector.?

```
private var slotMC:MovieClip;
    private var slotV1:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
    private var slotV2:Vector.<MovieClip>;
    private var slotV3:Vector.<MovieClip>;

    public function InputSlot():void {
        registerClassAlias("MovieClip", MovieClip);
        for (var i:int = 1; i < typeAmount + 1; i++) {                      
            SlotClass = Main.queue.getLoader('main_uiMC').getClass('slot0' + i) as Class;
            slotMC = new SlotClass();
            slotMC.name = "slot" + i;

            //push to vector before randomly add to stage
            slotV1.push(slotMC);
        }

        slotV2 = clone(slotV1);
        trace('slotv2', slotV2);
    }

    private function clone(source:Vector.<MovieClip>):Vector.<MovieClip> {  
        var myBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        myBA.writeObject(source);
        myBA.position = 0;

        return myBA.readObject() as Vector.<MovieClip>;
    }
```

It returns null for the slotV2.
Or in this case would a multidimensional Vector would be a better way?
I'm not sure what other info I would add into the MC in the future though.

Comment: Do you need a deep clone (aka copies of the MCs in the first vector) or shallow clone (only links are copied, no more MCs are created)?

Comment: both 3 slot will need to have the MC added to stage, so i think its a deep clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot deep-clone a vector of `DisplayObject`s of any kind, unless the objects' classes implement `IExternalizable`. This is because deeply cloning a `DisplayObject` requires cloning all its references including the entire children list and stage, and you cannot make another stage. Thus, you'd better create your "deep clone" by creating more instances of `SlotClass` in the cycle and stuffing them into corresponding vectors.

```
for (var i:int = 1; i < typeAmount + 1; i++) {                      
        SlotClass = Main.queue.getLoader('main_uiMC').getClass('slot0' + i) as Class;
        slotMC = new SlotClass();
        // slotMC.name = "slot" + i; 
        // drop name setting, you'd better use position in vector to refer to the clip

        //push to vector before randomly add to stage
        slotV1.push(slotMC);
        slotMC = new SlotClass();
        slotV2.push(slotMC);
        slotMC = new SlotClass();
        slotV3.push(slotMC);
    }
```

Don't forget to initialize the vectors prior to running the cycle.

As a side point, yes it *might* be better to use a multidimensional vector, considering why do you need these several vectors.